# Shortest way to output 0 if meta does not have value / is empty

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, is-empty

Hope that title makes sense, I have a few meta fields that I want to output `0` if they are empty.

I'm currently outputting the values with this:

```
<?php meta('some-field'); ?>
```

Edit:  the above code will echo out the value

Comment: `<?php echo (empty(emta('')) ? "0": meta('some-field')) ?>` maybe this helps you

Comment: You don't need the empty() function call, because null and empty string would cast to false. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example use the ternary operator.
After PHP 5.3:

```
echo meta('some-field') ? : 0;
```

Before PHP 5.3:

```
echo meta('some-field') ? meta('some-field') : 0;
```

Comment: echo meta('some-field') ? : 0; seems to output an additional 0 even when the meta has a value so value of word is now word0 and 4000 is 40000, couldn't get the other suggestions working really.

Comment: Your function returns with that value and don't try to print it?

Comment: Not sure what you mean ?

Comment: Your meta function ends with return $something and not echo $something? Just to be sure. :)

Comment: Yeah I believe it echos it using https://wordpress.org/plugins/more-fields/    so that's the code I was using, I'm outputting the data into js Google charts to be exact.

Comment: Ah, okay, then try Simone Nigro's solution with output buffering, because it'll catch the echo's result!

Comment: Tried that seems to break the page :( did a code check and got Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in your code on line 1

Comment: Ended up using it but before the code that I was using is generated so works perfectly Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

assuming `meta()` write and not return anything...

```
function callback($buffer) {
    // check if buffer is empty, else return 0
    return (!empty($buffer)) ? $buffer : 0;
}

// turn output buffering on. the output is stored in an internal buffer. 
// The callback function will be called when the output buffer is flushed
ob_start('callback');

meta('some-field');

// Flush the output buffer
ob_end_flush();
```

working example:
http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/42rr-zh8j

---

assuming `meta()` return value and not write anything...

```
// Check if meta return value is empty, print meta value else print 0
echo ( !empty(meta('some-field')) ) ? meta('some-field') : 0;
```

Comment: Good call with return!

Comment: @Gerifield I know... but for a newbie is perhaps easier to understand

Comment: I get Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in your code on line 1  on checking my code cause it seems to break the page not sure what to do..

Comment: @AlexSzymanowski There is an error in your code between `ob_start` and `ob_end_flush`

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap `meta()` in a custom function of your own:

```
function myMeta($key, $default = '0') {
   $meta = meta($key);
   return empty($meta) ? $default : $meta;
}
```

and use it instead of meta:

```
myMeta('some-field');
myMeta('some-field', 'other-default-value');
```